# Does Java Berkeley DB have an upper limit for concurrent reading?

Tags: java, berkeley-db-je

Java Berkeley DB is used in my system to store persistent data.

Since I have a large amount of data to be loaded, I attempt to do that with a number of threads. When the number of threads is low, e.g., 10, it works fine. However, when it is set to a higher value, e.g., 30, the reading processes get stuck. It looks like the Java Berkeley DB has an upper limit for concurrency reading? Am I right? How would I update the limit?

Answer (score 0):

Did you say ... "to be ***loaded***?"

Uh huh, thought you did!

Therefore, the threads that you speak of are **not** "reading" threads: they are "writing" threads!

And, guess what:  they are **competing** with one another, and, guess what, they are losing!

Unfortunately, your "attempt" to speed things up through the use of threads was *(IMHO ...)* "sincere, but misguided." Ultimately, a Berkely DB is "a single, on-disk data structure," and so there are *(IMHO...)* **no** opportunities for speeding-up the process through the use of multi-threading.

Various other strategies, though, might work. For example, you might find that if you **sort** the records that are to be inserted, through some appropriate external command, the process of inserting those records might well become “usefully *(much?)* faster.” Enough of a speed-difference, in other words, to more-than(!) make up for the time spent sorting. *(However, there will only be one way to find out if this is true in **your** situation: "benchmarking, your using actual data, your actual sort-command, and so on.")*